# Get Bitmap from Redis in binary

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, redis

I am working on a user activity feature in which I track the activity of a user everyday. I am thinking of using bitmap, so users who will be active on that day will be set to 1.

```
SETBIT users:2015:9:30 <userid> 1
```

I don't want to do GETBIT for each user. I want to retrieve the entire value in binary so I can iterate through it and find the active or inactive users.

I would like to know if this approach is correct and which node-module to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the bitarray you should set return_buffers as true and then do a get operation on it this will give you a buffer object. Convert this buffer object to hex string and then iterate through it.

My solution

```
neoredis = require 'redis'
key = "h"
map =
  "0":[]
  "1":[3]
  "2":[2]
  "3":[2,3]
  "4":[1]
  "5":[1,3]
  "6":[1,2]
  "7":[1,2,3]
  "8":[0]
  "9":[0,3]
  "a":[0,2]
  "b":[0,2,3]
  "c":[0,1]
  "d":[0,1,3]
  "e":[0,1,2]
  "f":[0,1,2,3]
usersbufferobject = null

redis = neoredis.createClient(6379,'redis',{return_buffers:true})
redis.get key,(err,res)->
  redis.quit()
  if not err?
    if res?
      usersbufferobject = res.toString('hex')
      users = []
      offset = 0
      arr = usersbufferobject.match(/.{1,2}/g)
      for i in arr
        for j in map[i[0]]
          users.push(offset+j)
        for j in map[i[1]]
          users.push(offset+4+j)
        offset+=8
      console.log "Active Users",users
    else
      console.log "No users active"
  process.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit arrays in Redis are stored as strings. To get the entire array, just do a regular GET and parse the bytes from the result.

Comment: I am trying to do GET but I am not able to parse it to binary. Please check this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32885532/get-operation-on-redis-bitmap-returns-weird-output>