# Get operation on Redis bitmap returns weird output

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, redis

I am doing setbit operation in redis to mark which users have been online on a particular day.

I am doing a redis get operation to get the value of the key.

```
coffee> redis.setbit "a",7,1
true
coffee> redis.setbit "d",4,1
true
coffee> redis.setbit "g",1,1
true
coffee> redis.setbit "h",0,1
```

And the output is

```
coffee> redis.get "a",(err,res)->console.log res.toString().charCodeAt(0)
true
coffee> 1

coffee> redis.get "d",(err,res)->console.log res.toString().charCodeAt(0)
true
coffee> 8

coffee> redis.get "g",(err,res)->console.log res.toString().charCodeAt(0)
true
coffee> 64

coffee> redis.get "h",(err,res)->console.log res.toString().charCodeAt(0)
true
coffee> 65533
```

My problem is with the "h" key where I am setting the 0th bit 1. It should return 128 but returns 65533.Why is this so?

My end goal is to get bitmap from redis in binary so that I can get which users were active on that particular day.

Comment: Are you parsing a unicode character perhaps?

Comment: No it is a bitmap in redis, so it can be any random string depending on which bits will be set to 1

Comment: When tested via redis-cli, `GET h` returns "\x80" (or 128 decimal).

Comment: Yes I checked it too, I am getting a buffer object with 80 , but when converted to string it returns 65533. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like there's something wonky with the client module and/or stack settings. Still suspecting a character set gremlin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs because of utf-8 encoding. When we set the 0th bit as 1, it does not follow utf-8 rules. Now when we try to get it we get the replacement Character

> U+FFFD � replacement character used to replace an unknown or
>   unrepresentable character

and when we do a charCodeAt on it we will get 65533.

Read here [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) and [Specials Unicode Block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block))

Answer (score 0):

The secret is to put "return_buffers: true" when you connect.  This causes buffers rather than strings to be returned on any function calls that use that redis client.

```
const client = redis.createClient({
    host: '192.168.1.89',
    port: 6379,
    return_buffers: true
    });
```